# Shouldn't the newer questions be marked as duplicate and not the earlier ones?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Example:

The Stack Overflow question *[What is the reason behind "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290884/what-is-the-reason-behind-non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static/290911)* asked in 2008 is marked as duplicate of *[Non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559527/non-static-variable-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context)* which was asked *later* (2010), shouldn't it be the other way around/a mechanism to prevent people from doing such silly things?

Comment: Not a duplicate.  That one is about how to workaround the currently broken system, mine is a bug report to fix it.

Comment: It is not a bug and not a broken system. It is an intentional policy, that question with better answers should stay open, and similar questions with less useful answers should be closed. See my suggestion to include reference to this policy in "possible duplicate" comments [Add clarification link to "Possible duplicate" automated comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281980).

Comment: I used to think the same as you but over time I have realized that it is far more efficient to sometimes make older questions duplicates of newer ones rather than trying to always bring the oldest duplicate up to the quality necessary for it to be the "master".

Answer (score 5):

What if the newer duplicate has better answers?

Wouldn't it be better to link to the post with the better answer/s than simply rely on the time a post was made?

That's the logic behind not constraining duplicates targets to be the older posts.

Comment: If the newer one has better answers, then we've failed in another way.  It should have been closed as duplicate to begin with before it was answered.

Comment: "then we've failed in another way"? huh?

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch: You are right that "It should have been closed as duplicate to begin with before it was answered". But it wasn't and now we have a choice which one to close. The policy is to select  to close the one with less useful answers.