# Add clarification link to "Possible duplicate" automated comment

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, automatic-comments

Some people when receiving "Possible duplicate" comment (if someone voted to close the question as a duplicate), take it personally and put angry comments, that historically their question was asked first, and shouldn't be closed.
Lack of clarity causes new  questions to be raised such as [Shouldn't the newer questions be marked as duplicate and not the earlier ones?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281977/shouldnt-the-newer-questions-be-marked-as-duplicate-and-not-the-earlier-ones)

It will be good to add information/help  icon (i) with the link to a clarification page to be like

> Possible duplicate [(i)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha?noredirect=1&lq=1) of [Generic TryParse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961656/generic-tryparse)

or just make Possible duplicate clickable

> [Possible duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha?noredirect=1&lq=1) of [Generic TryParse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961656/generic-tryparse)

The clarification page can be meta question [Should I vote to close a duplicate question, even though it's much newer, and has more up to date answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha) or a new service center help page with a similar content.

Comment: I disagree adding this to  the comment. However, this can be added to the banner only the OP can see

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I prefer to have help link  visible to everyone, who is curious what "possible duplicate" means. But explanation to author of closing question is better than nothing. You can write your idea as an answer.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, Please see an example 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676245/c-sharp-dictionary-making-the-key-case-insensitive-through-declarations
,that not only authors need explanation, why date is not essential, when determine a duplicate

Comment: Well, since you also offer a way without any noise (linking existing text) this might not be a bad idea.